# Updatable Random Forests

Tags: weka, prediction, random-forest, forecasting

I use Random Forests for data forecasting and would like to continuously update the trained model using only new data instead of periodically re-training the model on the whole historical data. It seams to me that RF is not built to be updatable but ?

I use Weka's RF but any theoretical solution or experience on another solution could be of great help. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weka's RF indeed doesn't have an option for dynamic retrain, but there are other algorithms (variations of the original RF) which have this option. This is one example: 
http://www.ymer.org/amir/software/online-random-forests/

Comment: have you already tried the Online RF from Amir ? Do you how does it compare with weka off-line RF in terms of classification performance ?

Comment: @doxav have you tried this? In my case, I have around 1.4 million instances (rows of data) and 57 features in csv file. Have you tested this online random forest personally and evaluate the performance? I was using random forest from weka, produced a model for fold 1 (out of 10 fold cross-validation) which took around 7.1 hours. So I am very keen on porting this to java and swift for my testing (wondering if performance can be improved).